# How to sort .csv files in R

Tags: r, sorting, columnsorting

I have one .csv file which i have imported into R. It contains a column with locations, some locations are repeated depending on how many times that location has been surveyed. I have another column with the total no. of plastic items.

I would like to add together the number of plastic items for locations that appear more than once, and create a separate column with the total no. of plastic and another column of the no. of times the location appeared.

I am unsure how to do this, any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: can you do a dput of your data? if your data are called say data do a dput(data) and show us the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

```
data %>% 
   group_by(location) %>% 
   mutate(TOTlocation=n(),TOTitems=sum(items))
```

And here's a base solution that does pretty much the same thing:

```
data[c("TOTloc","TOTitem")]<-t(sapply(data$location, function(x)
          c(TOTloc=sum(data$location==x),
            TOTitem=sum(data$items[data$location==x]))))
```

Note that in neither case do you need to sort anything - in `dplyr` you can use `group_by` to have each action done on only the part of the data set that belongs to a group determined by the contents of a certain column. In my base solution, I break down the locations list using `sapply` and then recalculate the TOTloc and TOTitem again for each row. This may not be a very efficient solution. A better solution will probably use `split`, but for some reason I couldn't make it work with my made up dataset, so maybe someone else can suggest how to best do that.

Comment: sorry, don't know what I was thinking with the first suggested solution - this revised one should work.

Comment: Happy to help. Please accept the answer if it solved your problem.